# Why is $M_n(D)$ a right quotient ring?

Tags: ring-theory, division-ring

Let $n$ be an interger and $D$ a division ring. I want to understand why $R=M_n(D)$ (the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $D$) is a right quotient ring (or a classical quotient ring).

I know that it suffices to understand why every regular element of $R$ has an inverse in $R$, but I have no idea why this is true. I've attempted constructing something similar to a determinant and using the methods we use when working with $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, but it's very long winded and hard to generalise.

I've also attempted using Ore's Condition and Goldie's theorem, but these only show existence.

Is there a quick explanation, or am I just going to have to bite the bullet and do a lot of work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume $R=M_{n}(D)$ is a finite dimensional algebra over some field $K$. Assume $r$ is a regular element of $R$. Consider $f_{r}:R\to R,\, x\mapsto rx$. Since $r$ is regular, $f_{r}$ is injective, hence surjective. Consequently, there is some $s$ in $R$ with $rs=1_{R}$. This shows that $r$ has a right inverse. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Why would $R$ be finite dimensional over a field? Anyway, it is always a finite-dimensional bimodule over $D$, so I think your argument works even without $K$.

Comment: In my experience, people often reserve the term division algebra for algebras that are finite dimensional over their center, e.g. in the context of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem. If $R$ is finite dimensional over a field, injective $\Rightarrow$ surjective is just a basic linear algebra fact. You are probably right that the assumption is unnecessary, though.

Comment: *If  is finite dimensional over a field, injective ⇒ surjective is just a basic linear algebra fact.* I would say that "an injective $D$ linear transformation of $D^n$ is surjective" is *also* a basic linear algebra fact, although maybe not an undergraduate one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I haven't done much algebra regarding algebras (if that makes sense?), so I do have a few questions. How are we able to assume $R$ is a finite dimensional algebra? Also, how does $R$ being a finite dimensional algebra allow us to determine that $f_r$ is surjective? Is the idea similar to that of "injective and finite $\Rightarrow$ surjective"?

Comment: @William An injective endomorphism of a finite dimensional vector space (over a field, or even a division ring) is onto, because the image has the same dimension as the whole space.

Comment: @rschwieb so we aren't using properties of algebras, we are just treating $R$ as a finite vector space over $D$? I think I understand now, thank you.

Comment: @William Yes, that is all that is necessary, if you're aware that all the concepts like dimensionality and so on hold for division rings just like they do for fields.  You don't need to worry about $D$ being an algebra over a field.